# Moving Magento - SUPER privileges issue

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, hosting, privileges

i'm moving my Magento website from my actual provider to a new Cloud solution.
I have some issues while importing the database because some SQL lines require SUPER privileges and my new hosting cannot read them.
How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The likely issue is that the database import you're using contains DEFINER statements.

You can remove those before importing to avoid the issue with SUPER PRIVILEGES.

You can get rid of those using sed on the command line:

```
sed -i 's|DEFINER=[^*]*\*|\*|g' databasedump.sql
```